# How to allow user to create and save marker on Firebase Database

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to users to add and save markers on Firebase database.
   i am unsure of how to do it, i currently have the user adding the marker and saving it but it does not appear on others users app.

```
public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng latLng) {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View v = li.inflate(R.layout.alert_layout, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setView(v);
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            EditText title = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.ettittle);
            EditText snittle = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.etsnittle);

            Marker marker0 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(title.getText().toString()).snippet(snittle.getText().toString())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.tackshops)));
            hash.put(marker0, R.drawable.agriculture);
            prefs.edit().putString("Lat",String.valueOf(latLng.latitude)).apply();
            prefs.edit().putString("Lng",String.valueOf(latLng.longitude)).apply();

            locationCount++;



            editor.putString("title"+(locationCount-1), title.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("snippet"+(locationCount-1),snittle.getText().toString());




        }
    });
```

this is my method for saving the marker on the Firebase Database

```
private void drawMarker(final LatLng latLng){


    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Agriculture marker = userSnapshot.getValue(Agriculture.class);

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng))
                        .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.tackshops));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Failed to read value


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving data into FireBase :

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

databaseReference.child("Sample_My_Location").push().setValue(l);
```

And you can see your data as JSON structure on FireBase console at https://console.firebase.google.com/ .

Make sure you have successfully setup firebase in your project. Check here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0

Answer (score 0):

You should save coordinates of your location (Lat Long) on Firebase. And then you can retrieve and show markers on Map.
[Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) this will let you know how to save and retrieve data.

Comment: any code example would help @AkshaySoni ive been reading that documentation im not getting it right

Comment: Ravi Tamada's this example will help you.     http://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/

Comment: Just like he save User Credential in Firebase Realtime, You save Latitude and Longitude.